# calculating distance between two numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I was interested in calculating various spatial distances between two numpy arrays (x and y).

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

x = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[11,22,23,24,5],
               [25,26,27,28,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])
i,j,k = x.shape

xx = x.reshape(i,j*k).T

y = np.array([[[31,32,33,34,5],
               [35,36,37,38,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[41,42,43,44,5],
               [45,46,47,48,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])

yy = y.reshape(i,j*k).T

results =  cdist(xx,yy,'euclidean')
print results
```

However, above results produces too many unwanted results. How can I limit it for my required results only.

I want to calculate distance between [1,11] and [31,41]; [2,22] and [32,42],...and so on.

Comment: Are you only interested in the Euclidean distance, or do you also want the option of computing the other distances provided by `cdist`?  If just the Euclidean distance, that's a one-liner: `np.sqrt(((xx - yy)**2).sum(axis=1))`.

Comment: I want to calculate other distances as well,mainly mahalanobis,cityblock,correlation

Comment: I don't know why someone downvoted this; here's a +1 to compensate.

Comment: Downvote certainly wasn't from me... People are far too free with downvotes these days...

Comment: I think your question points out a gap in the API.  `pdist` and `cdist` compute distances for all combinations of the input points. That is, they apply the distance calculation to the outer product of the input collections.  There isn't a corresponding function that applies the distance calculation to the inner product of the input arguments (i.e. the pairwise calculation that you want).  For any given distance, you can "roll your own", but that defeats the purpose of a having a module such as `scipy.spatial.distance`.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Alternatively, the individual functions in `scipy.spatial.distance` could be given an axis argument or something similar. It would avoid the hack of having to use `apply_along_axis`.  It looks like it would only require a few tweaks to `scipy.spatial.distance._validate_vector`.

Comment: @JoeKington: That's one of the alternatives I was just thinking about.  How about submitting a pull request at https://github.com/scipy/scipy? :)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Having 'axis' parameter in scipy.spatial.distance would be easier way-I think.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - As always, it's a touch more complicated than I thought it was.  I'll keep working at it though.  It would definitely be useful!

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser - Or even `np.linalg.norm(xx - yy, axis=1) `  .

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you just want the distances between each pair of points, then you don't need to calculate a full distance matrix.

Instead, calculate it directly:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[[1,2,3,4,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[11,22,23,24,5],
               [25,26,27,28,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])

y = np.array([[[31,32,33,34,5],
               [35,36,37,38,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]],
              [[41,42,43,44,5],
               [45,46,47,48,5],
               [5,6,7,8,5]]])

xx = x.reshape(2, -1)
yy = y.reshape(2, -1)
dist = np.hypot(*(xx - yy))

print dist
```

To explain a bit more about what's going on, first we reshape the arrays such that they have a 2xN shape (`-1` is a placeholder that tells numpy to calculate the correct size along that axis automatically):

```
In [2]: x.reshape(2, -1)
Out[2]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  5],
       [11, 22, 23, 24,  5, 25, 26, 27, 28,  5,  5,  6,  7,  8,  5]])
```

Therefore, when we subtract `xx` and `yy`, we'll get a 2xN array:

```
In [3]: xx - yy
Out[3]: 
array([[-30, -30, -30, -30,   0, -30, -30, -30, -30,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0],
       [-30, -20, -20, -20,   0, -20, -20, -20, -20,   0,   0,   0,   0,
          0,   0]])
```

We can then unpack this in to `dx` and `dy` components:

```
In [4]: dx, dy = xx - yy

In [5]: dx
Out[5]: 
array([-30, -30, -30, -30,   0, -30, -30, -30, -30,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0])

In [6]: dy
Out[6]: 
array([-30, -20, -20, -20,   0, -20, -20, -20, -20,   0,   0,   0,   0,
         0,   0])
```

And calculate the distance (`np.hypot` is equivalent to `np.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2)`):

```
In [7]: np.hypot(dx, dy)
Out[7]: 
array([ 42.42640687,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,
         0.        ,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,
        36.05551275,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ])
```

Or we can have the unpacking done automatically and do it all in one step:

```
In [8]: np.hypot(*(xx - yy))
Out[8]: 
array([ 42.42640687,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,
         0.        ,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,  36.05551275,
        36.05551275,   0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ,
         0.        ,   0.        ,   0.        ])
```

If you want to calculate other types of distances, just change `np.hypot` to the function you'd like to use.  For example, for Manhattan/city-block distances:

```
In [9]: dist = np.sum(np.abs(xx - yy), axis=0)

In [10]: dist
Out[10]: array([60, 50, 50, 50,  0, 50, 50, 50, 50,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0])
```

Comment: Actually I wan to calculate many other distances as mentioned in cdist

Comment: Thanks for your nice explaination. I also want to calculate other distances: mahalanobis, correlation. So is not it possible to reduce the matix obtained from cdist into required ones.

Comment: @simen - Sure, just call `np.diag(dist_matrix)`.  However, that will make _many_ unnecessary calculations.

Comment: yes, for performance using cdist is too slower for my need. if I had known the equations for other distances as well, your method is  super fast.

Comment: accepted for your contribution, and look forward to seeing the required functionality in scipy.spatial.distance