# Calculate pairwise distance of multiple trajectories using numpy

Tags: python, numpy

Given an arbitrary number of 3D trajectories with N points (timesteps) each, I would like to compute the distance between each point for a given timestep.

Let's say we'll look at timestep 3 and have four trajectories t_0 ... t_3. The point of the third timestep of trajectory 0 is given as t_0(3). I want to calculate the distances as follows:

```
d_0 = norm(t_0(3) - t_1(3))
d_1 = norm(t_1(3) - t_2(3))
d_2 = norm(t_2(3) - t_3(3)) 
d_3 = norm(t_3(3) - t_0(3))
```

As you can see there is kind of circular behavior in it (the last one calculates the distance to the first one), but that is not strictly necessary.

I know how to write some for-loops and calculate what I want to. What i am looking for is a concept or maybe an implementation in numpy (or combinations of np-functions) which can perform this logic just using the right axis and other numpy magic.

Here some example trajectories

```
import numpy as np

TIMESTEP_COUNT = 70
origin = np.array([0, 0, 0])

run1_direction = np.array([1, 0, 0]) / np.linalg.norm([1, 0 ,0])
run2_direction = np.array([0, 1, 0]) / np.linalg.norm([0, 1, 0])
run3_direction = np.array([0, 0, 1]) / np.linalg.norm([0, 0, 1])
run4_direction = np.array([1, 1, 0]) / np.linalg.norm([1, 1, 0])

run1_trajectory = [origin]
run2_trajectory = [origin]
run3_trajectory = [origin]
run4_trajectory = [origin]

for t in range(TIMESTEP_COUNT - 1):
    run1_trajectory.append(run1_trajectory[-1] + run1_direction)
    run2_trajectory.append(run2_trajectory[-1] + run2_direction)
    run3_trajectory.append(run3_trajectory[-1] + run3_direction)
    run4_trajectory.append(run4_trajectory[-1] + run4_direction)

run1_trajectory = np.array(run1_trajectory)
run2_trajectory = np.array(run2_trajectory)
run3_trajectory = np.array(run3_trajectory)
run4_trajectory = np.array(run4_trajectory)
```

... results in the following image:
[image]

Thank you in advance!!

EDIT:
My question is different to the suggested answer below because i don't want to calculate a full distance matrix. My algo should work with the distances among consecutive runs only.

Comment: So `runX_trajectory` are the arrays you need to calc distances for?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [calculating distance between two numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27678583/calculating-distance-between-two-numpy-arrays)

Comment: Maybe you should include your for loop implementation to illustrate what you are trying to do.  It seems like you want to do - `np.linalg.norm(run1_trajectory-run2_trajectory, axis=1)` or `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(run1_trajectory,run2_trajectory)[:,1]`

Comment: Or ... `w=scipy.spatial.distance.cdist(run1_trajectory,run2_trajectory); print(w.diagonal()[:10])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can stack them vertically to get an array of shape `4 x n_timesteps`, and then use `np.roll` to do the difference in each timestep, namely:

```
r = np.vstack([t0,t1,t2,t3])
r - np.roll(r,shift=-1,axis=0)
```

Numeric example:

```
t0,t1,t2,t3 = np.random.randint(1,10, 5), np.random.randint(1,10, 5), np.random.randint(1,10, 5), np.random.randint(1,10, 5)
r = np.vstack([t0,t1,t2,t3])
r
array([[1, 7, 7, 6, 2],
       [9, 1, 2, 3, 6],
       [1, 1, 6, 8, 1],
       [2, 9, 5, 9, 3]])

r - np.roll(r,shift=-1,axis=0)
array([[-8,  6,  5,  3, -4],
       [ 8,  0, -4, -5,  5],
       [-1, -8,  1, -1, -2],
       [ 1,  2, -2,  3,  1]])
```